# Best Fit Line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I need a line of best fit for each of the data points shown in this plot.
Here is my code so far.

```
load xsarea
load width
load depth
load da

figure;

loglog(da,width,'s',da,depth,'o',da,xsarea,'^');
xlabel('drainage area');
ylabel('depth/width/area');
hold on;

P = polyfit(log(da),log(width),1);
yfit = exp(P(1)+P(2).*log10(da));
plot(yfit,da,'ko');
label = ['log(depth) = 'num2str(p(1)) 'log(width) + 'num2str(p(2))];
```

As you can see it is logarithmic. When finished, the graph should look like figure 2 in [this document](https://s3.amazonaws.com/piazza-resources/hktmlt2s3a63mt/hor885x8970582/rv_hydraulicgeocurves.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOQYKAYOBKKVTKQ&Expires=1386825635&Signature=3fe8Ju6Dr7YGlzfoKBLyVTEs5o0%3D) Everything is pretty good, except I need the actual line to appear.

Comment: What is it doing now that's wrong?  Just plotting symbols but not lines?  It looks like you have yfit and da in the wrong order in plot.

Comment: It's actually fixed now. For future reference. What I used is this: load xsarea
    load width
    load depth
    load da

    
x=min(da):max(da); 

D=.96*x.^.30; 
W=13.1*x.^.44; 
A=12.38*x.^.75; 
d=loglog(da,depth,'or'); 
set(d,'marker','o','markersize',6,'markerfacecolor','r',... 
'markeredgecolor','r') 
hold on
w=loglog(da,width,'oc'); 
set(w,'marker','o','markersize',6,'markerfacecolor','r',... 
'markeredgecolor','c')
a=loglog(da,xsarea,'om'); 
set(a,'marker','o','markersize',6,'markerfacecolor','r',... 
'markeredgecolor','m')
grid on 
loglog(x,D,'b')
loglog(x,W,'b')
loglog(x,A,'b')